# ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-34tpfu29

Tags: python

When I install tablib[all]
command is: pip install tablib[all]

Always report errors as follows：

Preparing metadata (setup.py) … done
ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-34tpfu29

Ask for help. ths

I've upgraded both pip and setuptools to the latest version.
But the problem remains.
Some packages can be successfully installed. Such as xlrd, xlwt..

My python version

> python --version
> Python 3.8.8

Comment: Uninstall and then reinstall python